# Beginner - trying to scrape link and export to excel in Python and BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried to loop some web scraping from a demo site [Webscraper.io](https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops) - it's a demo site with laptops, where I'm trying to scrape the title of the laptop, the price and the link for the laptops. But I'm finding it very difficult to figure out, how to scrape all the information and exporting it to excel. Particularly how do I add the link to the current information?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url ="https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops"

r = requests.get(url)

html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

css_selector = {"class": "col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4"}

laptops = soup.find_all("div", attrs=css_selector)

for laptop in laptops:
    text = laptop.get_text()
    print(text)
```

But i still need some way to add the link for the laptops as well... and some way to export to scrapoing to excel.  '

I have tried to export the current data to excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(laptop)

df.to_excel("laptop_.xlsx", encoding="utf-8")
```

But i'm just getting a excel-file looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing out the laptop data. You will see that what is outputted is the same information in the Excel:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img alt="item" class="img-responsive" src="/images/test-sites/e-commerce/items/cart2.png"/>
<div class="caption">
<h4 class="pull-right price">$1799.00</h4>
<h4>
<a class="title" href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/544" title="Asus ROG Strix SCAR Edition GL503VM-ED115T">Asus ROG Strix S...</a>
</h4>
<p class="description">Asus ROG Strix SCAR Edition GL503VM-ED115T, 15.6" FHD 120Hz, Core i7-7700HQ, 16GB, 256GB SSD + 1TB SSHD, GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, Windows 10 Home</p>
</div>
<div class="ratings">
<p class="pull-right">8 reviews</p>
<p data-rating="3">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The part you say you want to extract is the link, which is found here:

```html
<a class="title" href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/544" title="Asus ROG Strix SCAR Edition GL503VM-ED115T">Asus ROG Strix S...</a>
```

One way you could get the link is by finding this tag inside of the `div` tag it's located in:

```py
for laptop in laptops:
    laptop_link = laptop.find('a') # Find the title link
    text = laptop_link.get_text()
    print(text)
```

Then, to get the hyperlink itself as opposed to the text inside, you need to get the tag's `href` attribute, like this:

```py
for laptop in laptops:
    laptop_link = laptop.find('a') # Find the title link
    text = laptop_link['href'] # Get the link attribute
    print(text)
```

Comment: I'm very much a beginner. I dont quite understand what you mean by "# Find the title link" I now the link is located here <a href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/545" class="title" title="Asus VivoBook X441NA-GA190">Asus VivoBook X4...</a>

but i',m having difficulties finding a way to add a code, that scrapes the link with the other info i'm scraping so far.

Do i need to add a new css_selector?

Comment: You're right, the link is there. The line `laptop.find('a')` will get the `<a>` tag that you are talking about. If you'll see, the link starts with `href="`. This means that you need to get the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag. You do this with `laptop_link['href']`. Please read my answer until the end, I wrote this there, if you need more help feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have now found a way to combine the text and links: 

`for laptop in laptops:
    laptop_link = laptop.find('a')
    text = laptop_link.get_text()
    href = laptop_link['href']
    full_url = f"https://webscraper.io{href}"
    print(text)
    print (full_url`

But when i'm exporting to excel, i'm getting the coded laptop data. And not just the info i'm seeing when printing text + full_url

Do you know, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You need to create a Dataframe with the information you want to save. It does not automatically save what you are printing. If my answer helped, you, you can mark it as correct with the check mark on the left. If you need help with another question, regarding Dataframes, you can open a new question.